# cannot identify YouTube traffic with ndpi-netfilter, when using Google Chrome

Tags: iptables, firefox, traffic-shaping, google-chrome, tc

I have `ndpi-netfilter` installed on Ubuntu and I need to shape the youtube traffic to 100kbps using tc module. I classify all youtube traffic to a one class through the iptables and apply tc class to shape the traffic.

It works fine when I use Firefox, but when I access youtube from Google Chrome, it doesn't work.

Bellow, are the rules and commands for `ndpi-netfilter` and `iptables`.

```
$ sudo tc qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: htb default 10  
$ sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1Mbps  
$ sudo tc class add dev eth1 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 100kbps ceil 100kbps prio 10

$ sudo iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.200.27 -m ndpi --youtube -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:10  
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.200.27 -m ndpi --youtube -j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:10
```

Anyone knows to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Does ndpi-netfilter handle QUIC protocol used by Chrome to load youtube videos ?
You can try to block UDP/443 in iptables output chain to force Chrome to use TCP/443 and see if it solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that YouTube uses the QUIC protocol on Google Chrome browser.

I successfully solved my problem by inserting QUIC Drop rule to the iptables.

```
$ sudo iptables -I POSTROUTING -m ndpi --quic -j DROP
```